# Create a XY Chart with non-contiguous data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to create a chart from non contiguous data as on the cart below (please ignore labeling, legend position and gridline for now):

- rngx1 and rngx2 refer to Horizontal Series
- rngy1 and rngy2 refer to Vertical Series
- Serie names addresses refer to Vertical Series -1 and Vertical Series -2.

[image]

```
    Sub CreateChart2()
'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are required)

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle4")
Dim rngx1 As Range
Dim rngx2 As Range
Dim rngy1 As Range
Dim rngy2 As Range


Set rngx1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select cells to link" _
    , Title:="Select data label values", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
Set rngy1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select cells to link" _
    , Title:="Select data label values", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)  ' Series1 -> PlotOrder = 1
Set rngx2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select cells to link" _
    , Title:="Select data label values", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
Set rngy2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select cells to link" _
    , Title:="Select data label values", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)  ' Series2 -> PlotOrder = 2
If Not rngx1 Is Nothing Then
    If Not rngy1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Union(rngx1, rngy1)
    End If
End If
If Not rngx2 Is Nothing Then
    If Not rngy2 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Union(rngx2, rngy2)
    End If
End If
'Create a chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
      Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
      Width:=300, _
      Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
      Height:=200)
    With cht
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Tabelle4!$I$2"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngx1
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngy1
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Tabelle4!$I$52"
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = rngx2
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = rngy2
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)
    End With

'Determine the chart type
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
      
End Sub
```

But i have a problem on this line:

```
        With cht
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Tabelle4!$I$2
```

What is wrong with this line, could you help me about this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the main difference from your previous post?

Comment: In the previous post, i was trying to get labels for each data point and the plot is present. Now i want to creat a chart from the data on the table. Indee my data table is bigger and more complex than the table on this post. In the next scenearia i want to iterate them between selected range and crate multiple graphs and i will make them label with the code from previous post . It is a kind of learning step by step. I hope you are not getting angry with me. I want to learn VBA and it is my project. And i am lucky that there are really wisdom guys like you out there. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after the chart is created, you try configure the series, but they do not exist! You have to create them first. Try to replace this part of the code.

Here, after the chart is created, it is selected and type is changed to XY Plot.

```
'Create a chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
  Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
  Width:=300, _
  Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
  Height:=200)

' Select chart
cht.Activate

'Determine the chart type
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    
With ActiveChart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Tabelle4!$I$2"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngx1
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngy1

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Tabelle4!$I$52"
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = rngx2
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = rngy2

    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Elio Fernandes. I am also happy that i am almost close to the solution. But the details are more important than anything, otherwise it doesn't work properly.